# Is there a method in python to numerically integrate data within curve_fit?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, curve-fitting, quad

Cannot use quad integration with data array. The code only runs when I substitute a number for the lower limit (0.5076 in the code supplied), the parameters returned are unrealistic and the estimated function "avoids" the data. When I use x or data or xx as the lower limit get an error message "ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"
Have attempted many variations, including using lambda attempting to solve this problem. I know this can be solved using numerical integration because I applied a FORTRAN program a few years ago on very similar problems. Have provided a small data array at the bottom which may be easily ignored.

```
import numpy as np
import csv
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from scipy import integrate as intg

#open data file, note this is a csv file type
with open("Riess_1998_D_L.csv","r") as i:
    rawdata = list(csv.reader(i, delimiter = ","))

exmdata = np.array(rawdata[1:],dtype=float)
#exmdata = np.array(np.random.random((10,4)),dtype=float) #convert to data array
xdata = exmdata[:,1]
ydata = exmdata[:,2]
error = exmdata[:,3]

#plot of imported data
plt.title("Observed SNe Ia Data")
plt.figure(1,dpi=120)
plt.xlabel("Expansion factor")
plt.ylabel("Distance (Mpc)")
#plt.plot(xdata,ydata,label = "Observed SNe Ia data")
plt.xlim(0.5,1)
plt.ylim(0.0,9000)
plt.xscale("linear")
plt.yscale("linear")
plt.errorbar(xdata, ydata, yerr=error, fmt='.k', capsize = 4)

"""
O_m and Hu are the unknown parameters which shall be estimated using the model and observational data
Guess values of O_m, which are between 0.01 and 1.0, guess values for Hu between 65 and 80(km/s/Mpc))
"""
init_guess = np.array([65,0.01])
bnds=([50,0.001],[80,1.0])

def funcZ(x,O_m):
    return 1/(x*np.sqrt((O_m/x) + (1-O_m)))

def integr(x,O_m):
    return intg.quad(funcZ, 0.5076, 1, args=(0.01))[0]

def funcX(x,O_m):
    return integr(x,O_m) * np.sqrt(abs(1-O_m)) 

litsped=299793 #the constant speed of light in a vacuum (m/s)

def funcY(x,Hu,O_m):
    return (litsped/(x*Hu*np.sqrt(abs(1-O_m))))*np.sqrt(abs(1-O_m)) * np.sinh(funcX(x,O_m))

params, pcov = curve_fit(funcY, xdata, ydata, p0 = init_guess, bounds = bnds, sigma = error, absolute_sigma = True)

est_Hu, est_O_m = params
estimate_Hu = round(est_Hu,2)
estimate_O_m = round(est_O_m,4)

chisq = sum((ydata - funcY(xdata,est_Hu,est_O_m)/error)**2)
chisquar = round(chisq,3)

#plot solution and estimated parameters
funcdata = funcY(xdata,est_Hu,est_O_m)
plt.plot(xdata, funcdata, label = "model")
print("\n")
print("The estimated Hubble constant: ", estimate_Hu)
print("\n")
print("The estimated normalised matter density: ", estimate_O_m)
print("\n")
print("The standard errors of the Hubble constant and matter density: ", np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov)))
print("\n")
print("A guesstimate for the goodness of fit is: ", chisquar)
"""
#The data are listed below, the order is row number, xdata, ydata, error

[[1.00000e+00 1.00000e+00 0.00000e+00 1.00000e-02]
 [2.00000e+00 9.91700e-01 3.99900e+01 2.40000e+00]
 [3.00000e+00 9.88400e-01 5.24800e+01 4.11000e+00]
 [4.00000e+00 9.86100e-01 6.08100e+01 3.08000e+00]
 [5.00000e+00 9.84300e-01 6.76100e+01 5.92000e+00]
 [6.00000e+00 9.84100e-01 7.14500e+01 3.95000e+00]
 [7.00000e+00 9.82200e-01 8.79000e+01 6.48000e+00]
 [8.00000e+00 9.80300e-01 9.41900e+01 4.77000e+00]
 [9.00000e+00 9.78400e-01 1.07150e+02 7.90000e+00]
 [1.00000e+01 9.76500e-01 1.19670e+02 9.93000e+00]
 [1.10000e+01 9.75800e-01 1.09650e+02 1.31600e+01]
 [1.20000e+01 9.74700e-01 1.18580e+02 1.25800e+01]
 [1.30000e+01 9.74400e-01 1.41910e+02 8.50000e+00]
 [1.40000e+01 9.72800e-01 1.57040e+02 1.44800e+01]
 [1.50000e+01 9.65900e-01 1.78650e+02 1.73000e+01]
 [1.60000e+01 9.65500e-01 1.72980e+02 1.67500e+01]
 [1.70000e+01 9.58700e-01 1.78650e+02 1.23500e+01]
 [1.80000e+01 9.56900e-01 2.40990e+02 1.88900e+01]
 [1.90000e+01 9.53400e-01 2.34420e+02 1.40400e+01]
 [2.00000e+01 9.52300e-01 2.29090e+02 1.79500e+01]
 [2.10000e+01 9.52100e-01 2.02300e+02 1.39900e+01]
 [2.20000e+01 9.51000e-01 2.54680e+02 1.40800e+01]
 [2.30000e+01 9.39800e-01 3.32660e+02 2.14600e+01]
 [2.40000e+01 9.30500e-01 3.63080e+02 2.84500e+01]
 [2.50000e+01 9.26100e-01 3.38840e+02 2.03000e+01]
 [2.60000e+01 9.19700e-01 4.38530e+02 3.84200e+01]
 [2.70000e+01 9.08300e-01 4.80840e+02 3.32400e+01]
 [2.80000e+01 8.89300e-01 6.33870e+02 3.79700e+01]
 [2.90000e+01 7.69200e-01 1.88799e+03 2.09090e+02]
 [3.00000e+01 7.24600e-01 2.11836e+03 1.95380e+02]
 [3.10000e+01 6.99300e-01 2.22844e+03 2.88140e+02]
 [3.20000e+01 6.99300e-01 3.23594e+03 3.73370e+02]
 [3.30000e+01 6.94400e-01 2.45471e+03 1.92370e+02]
 [3.40000e+01 6.75700e-01 3.09030e+03 2.42180e+02]
 [3.50000e+01 6.66700e-01 3.01995e+03 2.36670e+02]
 [3.60000e+01 6.36900e-01 3.56451e+03 3.12290e+02]
 [3.70000e+01 6.17300e-01 3.94457e+03 3.09130e+02]
 [3.80000e+01 5.07600e-01 7.55092e+03 1.04652e+03]]

"""
```

Comment: One error at a time with full traceback - if you want real help.  The `quad` issue is obvious - it requires scalar parameters.  You can, though, iterate, and apply it to multiple bounds in an list or array.  The abiguity error is the subject of many SO.  You are trying to a use a boolean array (or do some sort of array comparision) in a context that requires a scalar (an `if`, `or` etc).  Again, you are using an array in a place that requires a scalar.

Comment: Can you please suggest a "cure" with code for this problem? Unfortunately I am hoping to avoid iteration of the quad "solution", but it seems this is the only solution.

Comment: I agree with the comment of hpaulj. Can you please indulge me with specific code to solve this problem? The reason is that I will have to write another iteration to solve for the best value of O_m (the guess is now entered as an arg) and then write a search for the chisquar minimum for this specific iteration. I will then need to write another iteration on top of that when searching for three parameters - the current model is for two parameters.